# Insert SQL From Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have a questions.I want to transfer data from datatable to sql.Transferring the data received from the web service into datatable.I'm doing this operation with a loop.I do not want to do this operation with a loop.How I do? my codes;

```
DataTable gelendata = new DataTable();

private void cari_aktar()
{
    SqlCeConnection dataset_baglanti = conn.baglan();

    ARMINE_SHOP.WebReference.bulten terminal = new ARMINE_SHOP.WebReference.bulten();

    gelendata = terminal.CARILER_MAGAZACILIK("armine_webservice", "pass***", "MikroDB_V14_ARMINE").Tables[0];

    foreach (datarow row in gelendata.rows)
    {
        k = k + 1;
        progressbar1.value = k;

        if (row["cari_kod"] == dbnull.value)
        {
            cari_kod = "";
        }
        else
        {
            cari_kod = (string)row["cari_kod"];
        }
        sqlcecommand cari_ekle = new sqlcecommand("ınsert ınto carı_hesaplar (cari_kod) values (@cari_kod)", dataset_baglanti);
        cari_ekle.parameters.clear();
        cari_ekle.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I've tried codes

```
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

da.InsertCommand =new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO CARI_HESAPLAR (cari_kod) VALUES (@cari_kod)", dataset_baglanti);

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@cari_kod", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "cari_kod");

da.Update(terminal.CARILER_MAGAZACILIK("armine_webservice","pass***", "MikroDB_V14_ARMINE"));
```

Waiting for your help...

Thank u....

Comment: Have a look at this:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961535/bulk-insert-from-datatable-to-sqlce-datasource

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use this in SqlCe but in MsSqlConnection you can use like this

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmdb = (SqlCommandBuilder)this.CreateCommandBuilder();
cmdb.DataAdapter = (SqlDataAdapter)this.CreateDataAdapter(SQL, connection);
cmdb.RefreshSchema();
SqlDataAdapter dta = cmdb.DataAdapter;
dta.InsertCommand = cmdb.GetInsertCommand(true);
dta.UpdateCommand = cmdb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
dta.DeleteCommand = cmdb.GetDeleteCommand(true);
dta.Update(dataTable);
```

This copied from my own framework, for easy understand:

- CreateCommandBuilder is CommandBuilder Instancer
- CreateDataAdapter is DataAdapter Instancer where SQL is 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ??'
- GetInsertCommand is a INSERT Command

Comment: I tried but it did not. I need to speed up the transfer of data..thnk u.Waiting for your help....